# Hardware noise deppending on SO

Tags: noise

My PC is making a noise with a high frequency sound that is really annoying, although is not that loud.

I am trying to troubleshoot it, but withouth success. The most intriguing part is that when I switch to Windows, the noise is gone, but always happens when using Ubuntu.

I first thought it could be because my Ubuntu was on HDD and Windows on SSD, so I bougth a SSD for Ubuntu too and remove the HDD, but the sound still happens.

Looked at the MOBO's capacitor, but looks ok.
Any idea?

Comment: Which video card do you have?

Comment: My guess its either a fan, or the Ubuntu kernel is somehow draws more power from the board and stressing one of the small transformators.
For a start, check if acpi is turned on. If its on, then turn it off. See if that helps

Comment: I have a GTX 760

Answer (score 0):

Listen to video about "coil whine noise" to check if it's the same noise.

It depends on hardware and software activity, you may mitigate this to some point.

There's more info on howtogeek (I'm not sure I can link it from here, but you'll find it):
*coil whine refers to an undesirable noise emitted by an electronic component vibrating as power runs through an electrical cable. Just about anything with a power source can create coil whine to some degree, but it’s usually caused by an electrical current going through a power-regulating component like a transformer or inductor, causing its electrical wiring to vibrate at a variable frequency*

Comment: I took a look and its definitely not. For me is a steady high frequency. The noise might come and go, but the sound is always the same.